# Using Phenyx Pro IEM system 500 MHz in Italy

Tags: frequency, monitoring, radio

I want to use my Phenyx Pro IEM PTM-10 system for my band when we play at a wedding in Italy 2024.

The frequency range is 555-575 MHz.

Would anyone be able to tell me if I can use this without a license? If I need a license, any idea how much it will cost?

Any info is much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: This questions is not within our site scope. If you wish to find out about usage legality, you'll need to look at the spec of the device and read regulations for whatever country you are in.